# C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check on Mac

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors, configure

I am trying to install a software package called HYPRE on my Macbook (High Sierra 10.13.6). I follow the install instructions, which require me to first navigate to the appropriate folder and type ./configure in the terminal. This generates the error:

checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/Users/Tilton/FVM/HYPRE/hypre-master/src': configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check See` config.log' for more details

I searched around and saw some similar error issues reported online, but could not understand the issue. I am happy to share the config.log file, but it's very long ...

Comment: The preprocessor is sometimes `/usr/bin/cpp` on MacOS (tested on Mojave 10.14.6 — it annoys me that I'm not allowed to upgrade too).  You may be able to specify CPP=/usr/bin/cpp or something similar, either in the environment for the configure process or as a command line argument to the `configure` script.

Comment: Thanks so much Jonathan! That fixed the issue with configure, in that it now completes without error messages, but there is now an issue with running the subsequent makefile it generates. I looked in the makefile, and it seems the file has blanks where my c and fortran compilers should be. Sounds like there is still an issue with configure seeing my compilers. I am going to follow up directly with the developers of Hypre to see if they can help with that... Best Wishes!